# Add class to link when on specific pages

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have two routes that are both nested under the same resource, like so:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('dashboard', function() {
    this.route('foo');
    this.route('bar');
  });
});
```

Currently, in my `app/templates/application.hbs`, I have the navigation set up like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  {{#link-to "dashboard.foo" tagName="li"}}
    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Dashboard</a>
  {{/link-to}}
</ul>
```

That, obviously, links to `dashboard.foo`. However, that link also needs to be active on `dashboard.bar`. It has to point to `dashboard.foo` instead of `dashboard`.

I've tried creating a computed property in the application controller, like the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042737/ember-js-can-i-force-active-class-on-a-link-to-helper) question, but the currentPath never showed that it was on the dashboard. This is my attempt at it:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isDashboardRoute: function() {
    var routeName = this.get('currentRouteName');
    var currentPath = this.get('currentPath');
    console.log(routeName); // "loading"
    console.log(currentPath); // "loading"
  }.property('currentPath')
});
```

I then tried to add a dummy link-to that would show it as active (as described on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328295/how-do-i-bind-to-the-active-class-of-a-link-using-the-new-ember-router)), but it seems that it instead fires two events at once. This is that attempt:

```
// application.hbs
{{#link-to "dashboard" tagName="li" href=false eventName="dummy"}}
  {{#link-to "dashboard.foo"}}Dashboard{{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Any ideas?

**Edit**

After inserting the answer below into my code, here's what I now have:

```
{{#link-to "dashboard.foo" tagName="li" current-when="dashboard"}}
  <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>Dashboard</a>
{{/link-to}}
```

I couldn't have the nested `link-to` because it would mark both the `li` as well as the `a` as active, when I only needed the former to be active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `current-when` property.

```
{{#link-to "dashboard" tagName="li" href=false eventName="dummy" current-when="dashboard"}}
  {{#link-to "dashboard.foo"}}Dashboard{{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

There is also a feature flag for [ember-routing-multi-current-when](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/5fe2d63a7dab0484cad9e729886ac71b4c05f1fd/packages/ember-routing-handlebars/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L337)

Comment: Thanks! Instead of that first line, I only needed `{{#link-to "dashboard.foo" tagName="li" current-when="dashboard"}}`.